# 1 for 0 error when trying to extend built in Integer Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Keep getting the same error when extending the built-in Integer class.

```
class Integer
 def factorial
  if self < 0
   return 'You can\'t take the factorial of a negative number!'
  end
  if self <= 1
   1
  else
   self * factorial(self-1)
  end
 end
end


puts 12.factorial
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I fix it so that I can use my factorial method.

Comment: Hi @ACamilo, please clarify your question by adding more explanation, and showing the complete error that you get (if any) in the question, not in the title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
self * factorial(self-1)
```

`factorial` is an instance method, and it does not expect any arguments. Rather, you should call it on `self - 1`, like this:

```
self * (self - 1).factorial
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- `def factorial`
- `factorial(self-1)`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It might be an okay comment though.

Comment: @HolgerJust There is no question to the post. What question are you mentioning?

Comment: That is another problem. But even more so: when there is no question, there is no place for an answer.

Comment: Exactly. The best you can do is give a hint. And again, what question are you mentioning?

Comment: And the correct place to give vague hints or ask for clarification is the comments section, not an answer.

Comment: I did that already to the OP. But I am not asking the OP now. I am asking you. You wrote "This doesn't answer **the question**". What question are you mentioning?